# WinForms application is overwriting lines and adding data twice

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I have been learning C# for a while now but I have never actually had to use a database before. As of right now I am using a Local database (.mdf) and I have had nothing but problems. I would use SQL Server Management Studio and create the database and then add it to my visual studio project but I don't understand how to do that!

But my problem is this...I have some textboxes on my form and a save button. When the user clicks the save button all of the data in the textboxes will be saved to the database. The database is connecting just fine but when it saves the data it deletes the previous entry and then adds two of itself..this may make better sense if i show you:

So if I saved the following data to the database from the textboxes:

```
TEXTBOX         DATA IN TEXTBOXES
---------------------------------
txtNickname     facebook
txtURL          facebook.com
txtUsername     fbUsername
txtPassword     fbPassword
txtEmail        fbEmail@email.com
txtAbout        Facebook Social Media
```

Then it would enter that information into the database as shown below:

```
Id  Nickname  WebsiteURL     WebsiteUsername  WebsitePassword    WebsiteEmail         WebsiteAbout
1   Facebook  facebook.com   fbUsername       fbPassword         fbEmail@email.com    Facebook Social Media
```

Now, lets say that I close out of the program...and try to enter data back into the textboxes. One of two things will happen...the data will be gone, or the new data that I save will delete the old data and add two lines of the same data:

So I add this to the database now:

```
TEXTBOX          DATA IN TEXTBOXES
----------------------------------
txtNickname      twitter
txtURL           twitter.com
txtUsername      tbUsername
txtPassword      tbPassword
txtEmail         twitEmail@email.com
txtAbout         Twitter Social Media
```

And this is what happens when I look at the database:

```
Id  Nickname  WebsiteURL     WebsiteUsername  WebsitePassword    WebsiteEmail           WebsiteAbout
1   Twitter   twitter.com    tbUsername       tbPassword         twitEmail@email.com    Twitter Social Media
2   Twitter   twitter.com    tbUsername       tbPassword         twitEmail@email.com    Twitter Social Media
```

And like I said, either this happens or the data doesn't show up in the database at all. I will give you all of the code associated with the database below:

I have 7 textboxes and 2 buttons. Two of the textboxes are for password, one to verify that the passwords match and just txtPassword go into the database.

The textboxes are:

```
txtNickname
txtURL
txtUsername
txtEmail
txtPassword
txtPasswordAgain
txtAbout

btnSave
btnCancel
```

And the table is:

```
[dbo].[WebLogins]

[Id]              INT           IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
[Nickname]        VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[WebsiteURL]      VARCHAR (200) NULL,
[WebsiteUsername] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[WebsitePassword] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[WebsiteEmail]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[WebsiteAbout]    VARCHAR (200) NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

And the connection string in my app.config and settings is:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="PassLock.Properties.Settings.dbMainConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbMain.mdf;Initial Catalog=dbMain;Integrate Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

// NOTE: I added 'Initial Catalog=dbMain'
```

Just want to make sure I am doing this write...when I go and look in my solution explorer and server explorer I see 'dbMain.mdf' so I take it this is what my database name is!

And here is the rest of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PassLock
{
     string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PassLock.Properties.Settings.dbMainConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.WebLogins(Nickname, WebsiteURL, WebsiteUsername, WebsitePassword, WebsiteEmail, WebsiteAbout) " + "VALUES(@nickname, @websiteURL, @websiteUsername, @websitePassword, @websiteEmail, @websiteAbout)";

     public frmAddSite()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void frmAddSite_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          // I had this here, but then commented it out like I did below

          // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
          // con.Open();
     }

     private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          txtNickname.Enabled = false;
          txtPassword.Enabled = false;
          txtURL.Enabled = false;
          txtUsername.Enabled = false;
          txtEmail.Enabled = false;
          txtAbout.Enabled = false;
          cbShowPassword.Enabled = false;
          btnSave.Enabled = false;
          btnCancel.Enabled = true;

          using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
          using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
          {
               myCmd.Parameters.Add("@nickname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtNickname.Text.Trim();
               myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
               myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteURL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtURL.Text.Trim();
               myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websitePassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
               myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
               myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtAbout.Text.Trim();

               try
               {
                    conn.Open();
                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    int iAffectedRows = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (iAffectedRows > 0)
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show("Successful");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful");
                    }
                    conn.Close();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
               }
           }
      }
}
```

There is not any coding errors given by visual studio, I just don't understand this at all!! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` twice, which is why you are getting 2 rows for every save click.

As to the reason you are losing data or old data is showing up; It is probably because you are copying the mdf file as part of your build and it is overwriting the mdf file that has changes in it.

Answer (score 2):

Notice here you did ExecuteNonQuery twice?

```
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

int iAffectedRows = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is why the data got inserted twice, just remove the first line and it should work fine

Comment: @John Koemer thank you very much, I will try this when I get home and see what happens. I have the iAffectedRows int there because I need to figure out a way to programmatically determine if the query was successful. And yes it is copying the file everytime. Should I change this in the properties? Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @Andy by calling ExecuteNonQuery it automatically returns the number of effected rows, so you do NOT need to call it twice. Just remove the first myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery and it should work

Comment: Oh okay I get it! Thank you so much! One more quick question...whenever I restart the application all data in the database has been deleted...the database gets copied everytime the application starts...would those be the reason why I lose the data? And should I change the setting to something else

Comment: @Andy ofc if the database got deleted you would lose all of you data...wonder what library does that but you certainly would not want that to happen other than debugging purposes